# Find linked formula values from worksheets and replace with actual cell value

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheet, openxml, openxml-sdk

In a OOXML spreadsheet .xlsx you can through a linking formula fecth values from another spreadsheet and have them in your worksheet as values, that will always be updated when those values in another spreadsheet are updated.

I am using Open Xml SDK and I basically want to do what this does: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Formula/Remove-Formulas-from-Cells-but-Keep-Values-in-Excel-in-C.html

How do I:

- Find a value that has formula linking value to a cell in another spreadsheet
- Replace the formula value with the actual cell value
- Do this foreach cell in each worksheet in a spreadsheet

I have tried this so far: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-cells-in-a-spreadsheet

But I am recieving a `NullRefereceneException` each time the cell does not contain a formula or just any value. I have tried try-catch and several other ways to escape this exception, but it is not working.

But back to the challenge as outlined above; can anyone help me out?

Basic stuff such as `using SOME DIRECTIVE`, `foreach loop`, `Open()`, `Save()` I know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public void Remove_CellReferences(string filepath)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, true))
    {
        // Delete all cell references in worksheet
        List<WorksheetPart> worksheetparts = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.ToList();
        foreach (WorksheetPart part in worksheetparts)
        {
            Worksheet worksheet = part.Worksheet;
            var rows = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>(); // Find all rows
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                var cells = row.Elements<Cell>();
                foreach (Cell cell in cells)
                {
                    if (cell.CellFormula != null)
                    {
                        string formula = cell.CellFormula.InnerText;
                        if (formula.Length > 0)
                        {
                            string hit = formula.Substring(0, 1); // Transfer first 1 characters to string
                            if (hit == "[")
                            {
                                CellValue cellvalue = cell.CellValue; // Save current cell value
                                cell.CellFormula = null; // Remove RTD formula
                                                         // If cellvalue does not have a real value
                                if (cellvalue.Text == "#N/A")
                                {
                                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue("Invalid data removed");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    cell.CellValue = cellvalue; // Insert saved cell value
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Delete all external link references
        List<ExternalWorkbookPart> extwbParts = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.ExternalWorkbookParts.ToList();
        if (extwbParts.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ExternalWorkbookPart extpart in extwbParts)
            {
                var elements = extpart.ExternalLink.ChildElements.ToList();
                foreach (var element in elements)
                {
                    if (element.LocalName == "externalBook")
                    {
                        spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.DeletePart(extpart);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Delete calculation chain
        CalculationChainPart calc = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.CalculationChainPart;
        spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.DeletePart(calc);
    }
}
```